# Resolving Credential storage issue

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung, password, vpn

On Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 SMP600 when I try to to add a VPN I'm prompted for credential storage password. I have tried all the other solutions on SO and none of them worked. I have PIN code on the lock screen as well and I cannot clear the password as the option to do so is greyed out.

I talked to Samsung and they eventually told me I had to factory reset of the tablet! I want to know how to fix this once and for all. My device is rooted running stock ROM Kitkat 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a non-conventional solution (which might/might-not work for everyone) but can be helpful to others having the same issue.*

Answer gathered from [androidforum](http://androidforums.com/threads/fixed-working-fix-for-credential-storage-password-problem.848941/) and [google product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/wh0LNnnLpDA)

What we are trying to achieve is to Set-up a pin and fail to enter it deliberately to access recovery using  gmail address and entering the VPN settings directly after google sign-in.

---

Steps to achieve this:

1. Add a pattern lock and other information that goes with setting up a pattern-lock recovery.
2. Reboot phone and when the screen presents itself asking for lock pattern enter 5 failed attempts.
3. When theprompts says to wait 30 seconds, press OK and find the recovery button where you enter google account info.
4. After signing-in go straight to VPN settings and enter a new pattern-lock/pin.

---

If the above mentioned steps does not solve your issue go ahead with the alternative method.

Alternatively you can make use of 3rd party app called [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) and follow the steps as mentioned [here](http://www.pocketables.com/2014/02/fix-credential-storage-roadblock-android.html)

Comment: Sharath, I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question: OP didn't ask for a list of VPN apps (which would have been off-topic) – but about solving the issue with credential storage. Could you [edit] your post and fix that (before downvotes come hailing down on you)?

Comment: @Izzy thank you for letting me know. Edited now.  My bad, I thought it was a software rec post.

Comment: Yupp. Hint: SR=blue-favicon, ASE=green-favicon :) Or in my case, I take a look at the rep in the SE „MultiCollider™“ bar #D

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the tip, I'll keep that i mind. Also good tool, Multicolloder and also IzzyonDroid ;)

Comment: I have tried both of these methods before and even retried them now,  however neither of them work for me. Whenever I get the open VPN stage I'm  prompted for credential storage.

Comment: @preezzzy Did you try setting up a new pin in credential storage?

Comment: @Sharath The only place to set up a new pin is Device->Lock screen->Screen lock. I'm not sure what you mean by setting pin in credential storage. I followed your instructions until Step 4. When I go straight to VPN it doesn't ask me to set up a new pin it asks me "Enter password for credential storage".